# Does Excel for Mac support classes?

Tags: vba, excel

Simple question but my Google-Fu is letting me down and I don't have a Mac to test. Excel versions 2011+.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does support classes.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this will make it in the Google rankings one day :)